# How to make Illustrator default to CMYK

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-conversion, swatches

How to make Illustrator default to CMYK. My color box says CMYK, but my swatches still default to RGB please help.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator "defaults" to what an *existing* file is set to, or whatever you *tell* illustrator to use. There's no way to tell Illustrator to *always* use a particular color mode.

Open new files as CMYK:

[image]

OR

[image]

Illustrator uses whatever color mode you chose when opening a new file.

If you are opening **existing files**, you'll need to change the document color mode via `File > Document Color Mode`: [**SEE HERE**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48813/how-to-change-document-color-mode-in-illustrator)

You should also be aware of issues with merely switching document color modes: **[See here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5340/3270)**